# Can i use WebSphere 6.1 for JSFunit?

Tags: jsf, jsfunit

I am doing work on jsfunit, and i am using WebSphere6.1 application server so can anyone give me answer that is it compatible for JSFunit or i need to do some changes in my server configuration? if possible send me the example?

Thanks
Vinod

Answer (score 2):

Yes,

Read [JSFUnitOnWebSphere](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JSFUnitOnWebSphere):

> So to use WebSphere with JSFUnit, you
>   will need to create a class that
>   extends one of the
>   InitialRequestStrategy classes.  See
>   JSFUnitTestingSecurePages for other
>   examples, but the following should
>   work for non-secure pages

```
public class WebSphereRequestStrategy extends org.jboss.jsfunit.framework.SimpleInitialRequestStrategy {
   public Page doInitialRequest(WebClientSpec wcSpec) throws IOException {
      String jsessionid = wcSpec.removeCookie("JSESSIONID");
      wcSpec.addCookie("JSESSIONID", "0000" + jsessionid); // cache ID is 0000 by default
      return super.doInitialRequest(wcSpec);
   }
}
```

> Then you will use this code to start
>   your test:

```
WebClientSpec wcSpec = new WebClientSpec("/index.jsf");
wcSpec.setInitialRequestStrategy(new WebSphereRequestStrategy());
JSFSession jsfSession = new JSFSession(wcSpec);
JSFClientSession client = jsfSession.getJSFClientSession();
JSFServerSession server = jsfSession.getJSFServerSession();
```